# Numpy - Array range indexing in a axis

Tags: python, numpy

For example, If I have Numpy arrays which is initialised by:

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(6,2)
[out] array([[ 0,  1],
             [ 2,  3],
             [ 4,  5],
             [ 6,  7],
             [ 8,  9],
             [10, 11]])
```

and

```
mask = np.array([0, 2])
```

My target is to mask array by range in a axis. like this

```
for i in mask:
    target.append(a[i:i+3,:])
```

So, it should be:

```
[out] array([[[0, 1],
              [2, 3],
              [4, 5]],

             [[4, 5],
              [6, 7],
              [8, 9]]])
```

but that's inefficient. Then, I've tried

```
a[mask:mask+3,:]
```

but it said

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We could leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to generate all indices and index -

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])

In [21]: mask
Out[21]: array([0, 2])

In [24]: a[mask[:,None] + np.arange(3)]
Out[24]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7],
        [8, 9]]])
```

**Approach #2**

We can also leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for a more efficient solution -

```
In [43]: from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

In [44]: view_as_windows(a,(3,a.shape[1]))[mask][:,0]
Out[44]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7],
        [8, 9]]])
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you